# Java activity class in android studio

Tags: java, android, authentication, methods

Good evening everyone. I have been teaching myself on app development thus far and it's been rewarding. I have a bit of a question which in my opinion is basic...very basic. I have developed a project to the login screen phase working with java in android studio 4.2.now, my questions are;

1. On the login screen activity class, is it possible to have 2 methods implemented for both email&password login and social media login? My aim is to have one screen(login screen) that handles this activity with a firebase backend, and keeps the user logged in until such a time that the user logs out.
2. Can someone please recommend a reference that can aid my developing this page successfully?(i have scoured YouTube but i find only materials that talk either one (email&password authentication using firebase) or the other (social log on topics). Which prompted me to ask the first question.
3. Which is also based off of question 1; if i can have 2 methods implemented do i still have to "Override" before i can implement another method?

I really will appreciate any help offered.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebase UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) sounds like a good candidate for your problem because it handles multiple providers (email, socials, google and phone) so that you don't handle that yourself.

Firebase UI aims to eliminate boilerplate code and promote best practices both *user experience* and *security* when Authenticating.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm reading through right now. Do you think this would allow integration with instagram as well? Thanks once again @Tonnie

Comment: @DareTo Firebase UI doesn't Integrate with IG unfortunately.

Comment: Be sure to also check at [Firebase UI Read Me](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md) . Lots of useful info here.